# Rails 2.3: Need something like ActiveRecord#to_json that returns a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets say `Bookshelf has_many :books`.  I can dump a bookshelf to json, including it's associated books like this:

```
@bookshelf.to_json :include => [:books]
```

But I want a simple ruby hash instead.  I've tried `#attributes` but that doesn't appear to take any arguments.  And i've tried `#to_hash` but that method doesn't on `ActiveRecord::Base`.

I know I could do this:

```
JSON.parse @bookshelf.to_json(:include => [:books])
```

But that feels like a huge and ugly performance waste.  I'm sure it's compiled to a hash internally before its JSON-ified, so I dont want to have to do an extra round of encode/decode for no reason.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler, I mention that method above.  It doesn't take arguments like `to_json` does.  Making it much harder to include associations and the all the other awesomeness that is provided by the options.

Comment: Wow. Sorry. I must be half asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2.3 you can use `as_json`:

The `as_json` call is very helpful for this situation. It can take attributes and it returns a hash, though the keys are a little odd when you start including nested objects. Specifically, the keys for the current object are all strings, and the key for the handle of the nested object is a symbol.

So, for your example, your call could look something like:

`hash = @bookshelf.as_json(:include => {:author => {}, :books => {:include => :pages}})`

And access to the `hash` object would look something like:

```
hash["bookshelf_color"] #=> "White"
hash[:author]["name"] #=> "John Smith"
hash[:books][:pages]["format"] #=> "8.5 inches x 5.5 inches"
```

In Rails 3.0 you can use `serializable_hash`:

The v2.3 `as_json` functionality moved to the `serializable_hash` method. It works the same as the above (looking at the source code you can tell the v2.3 `as_json` method was moved to the v3.0 `serializable_hash` method).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to create a simple hash containing an object + an array of objects...but for the array you could simply do:

```
@bookshelf.books.map(&:attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@bookshelf.attributes.merge(:books => @bookshelf.books.map(&:attributes))
```

oh, even better, I belive you can get a hash using `as_json` which is actually internally called by `to_json`

```
@bookshelf.as_json :include => :books
```